# Django - datatable reload with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm looking for properly solution to reload datatable in Django with Ajax.

At this moment it works pretty good with one exception. Table are auto paged by bootstrap. When Ajax reload table it shows all results without splitting on the pages.

orders_list.html:

```
<div id="DataTables_Table_0_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">
        <div class="datatable-scroll">
        <table class="table datatable-basic dataTable table-striped no-footer" id="DataTables_Table_0" role="grid" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_0_info">
            <thead>
                <tr role="row">
                    <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="" aria-sort="ascending">Nr.</th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="">Data</th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="">Przewoźnik</th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="">Status</th>
                    <th class="text-center sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Akcje" style="width: 100px;">Akcje</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="orders_table">
                {% include "orders/orders_table.html" %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

orders_table.html:

```
{% for order in orders %}
    <tr role="row">
        <td class="sorting_1">{{ order.shop_order_id }}</td>
        <td class="">
            <span data-popup="tooltip" title="{{ order.date }}">
                {{ order.date|date:"M d, Y" }}
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>{{ order.carrier }}</td>
        <td>
            {% if order.packed %}
                <span class="label bg-grey">
                    Spakowano
                </span>
            {% else %}
                <span class="label label-info">
                    {{ order.status }}
                </span>
            {% endif %}
        </td>
{% endfor %}
```

javascript:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({    
       url: '/Project/zamowienia/orders_test',
          success: function(data) {
          $('#orders_table').html(data);
          }
    });
}, 10000)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', orders_list),
    url(r'^orders_test$', orders_list_test),
]
```

views:

```
def orders_list(request):
    orders = Order.objects.all().order_by('-shop_order_id')
    carriers = Carriers.objects.all().order_by('name')
    statuses = Status.objects.all().order_by('name')
    Status().import_status()
    Order().import_orders()
    return render(
            request, 'orders/orders_list.html', 
            {
                'namespace': 'Zamówienia',
                'icon': 'credit-card',
                'statuses': statuses,
                'carriers': carriers,
                'orders': orders
            }
        )


def orders_list_test(request):
    orders = Order.objects.all().order_by('-shop_order_id')
    return render(
                request, 'orders/orders_table.html', 
                {
                    'orders': orders
                }
            )
```

Comment: Sorry man, but i didn't understand. Can you provide a screen of the actual result and the expected result, please?

Comment: I would like to see: http://imgur.com/iq79NWq
But I see: http://imgur.com/EA9Epx9 (rows aren't paged)

I looking for better solution to refresh datable.

I apologize for not clearly communicate

Comment: yes, but i didn't see the pagination system in your templates.. Where is it?

Comment: It is controlled by jQuery plug-in datatable https://www.datatables.net

Comment: oh ok, after this `$('#orders_table').html(data);` add this `$(''#orders_table').DataTable();`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but still the same.

Comment: I did a mistake : `$('#orders_table').DataTable();` the browser console say something? Are you sure that this plugin works? Have you already managed to get the excepted result?

Comment: You means #DataTables_Table_0 because #orders_table is <tbody>. Yep, plugin works fine. DataTable() was called once and it doesn't work for subsequent calls. So for redraw I used .draw(). But on every refresh it reset my filters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious, use table.draw() :).